# The Format of my Query Causes a Data Conversion Error When the Query Should Never Encounter the Problem Entry

Tags: subquery, h2, data-conversion

I might have a misunderstanding on how a query works. I have a table with 3 columns (id, int1, int2) I'm interested in. int1 and int2 can contain positive integers or the '-' character. Due to reasons out of my control I cannot change the format and change '-' to represent integers. Below is my query.

```
CREATE TABLE table1 AS (SELECT id, int1, int2 FROM CSVREAD(someCSV));

SELECT count(id)
FROM (SELECT id, int1, int2
      FROM table1
      WHERE int1 NOT LIKE '-' AND int2 NOT LIKE '-')
WHERE int1 > 100 AND int2 > 100;
```

From my understanding the outer query should use the result of the subquery which means the outer query should not see any '-' but when I try to run this I get the following error

> Data conversion error converting "-";

I have a work around by using a case statement but I'd like to know why this does not work how I thought it would.

Edit:
I realized it sounds like a column can have '-' between integers. The entry will actually either have '-' or an Integer, not a combination of both. I added the creation of the table in the code snippet.

Sample table (This is also the format of the csv)

```
|---------|----------|--------|
|    id   |   int1   |  int2  |
|---------|----------|--------|
|    1    |   34     |  120   |
|---------|----------|--------|
|    2    |   -      |  -     |
|---------|----------|--------|
|    3    |   200    |  200   |
|---------|----------|--------|
|    4    |   15     |  90    |
|---------|----------|--------|
|    5    |   130    |  145   |
|---------|----------|--------|
```

The subquery returns all rows with only integers

Comment: I added table creation stament as well as a better description

Comment: That doesn't really change what I would have given as an answer.

Comment: Sorry my mistake for some reason i did not notice you also added a cast. Thanks, looks like the missing CAST was the issue. I'm still a little confused as to why casting it to an INT would fix a Data Conversion issue when isn't a Cast a Data Conversion?

Comment: The `int1` and `int2` columns aren't int _types_; they're text.  So, you need to cast them.  In some databases, such as MySQL, this would not be necessary.  Apparemtly it is needed in H2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is probably happening with the outer `WHERE` clause:

```
WHERE int1 > 100 AND int2 > 100
```

when it hits values of `int1` and/or `int2` which have dashes in them.  This is happening, perhaps contrary to what you think, because your `LIKE` expressions are wrong.  To check for a dash *anywhere* in the column you should be using something like this:

```
WHERE int1 NOT LIKE '%-%'
```

Here is your corrected query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM
(
    SELECT id, int1, int2
    FROM table1
    WHERE int1 NOT LIKE '%-%' AND int2 NOT LIKE '%-%'
) t
WHERE CAST(int1 AS INT) > 100 AND CAST(int2 AS INT) > 100;
```

We might be able to even improve upon the above query, e.g. by finding a way to eliminate the subquery.  But a better approach would be to stop mixing numeric and text data in the same column.  If you need `int1` and `int2` to behave as integer columns, then make them `INT` and only store integer data there.

Comment: Ideally, yes the columns should only contain INT if that's my goal but unfortunately I don't have control over the source data. I suppose I could create a temporary table though.